# Piface Digital Master and PiFace Relay Plus Slave

Tags: python, ssh, remote, ethernet-port, relay

I wish to control four state reconfigurable antennas in a propagation measurements using RPis at both ends of the propagation channel. The headless master RPi has a PiFace digital to control the start of measurements. The code will run through the states and wait for the command to repeat the measurements when ready.

The headless slave Pi, is equipped with PiFace Relay Plus. It is desirable to have the master select the antenna operation state and command the slave Pi to activate the desired state.

I wish to network the two Pis using Ethernet.

Would anyone be able to make some suggestions regarding networking the Pis. I have some initial idea on the codes but until a connection is established I am unable to test my codes.

Answer (score 0):

I settled to use TCP/IP sockets. One Pi is setup up as the master and the other slave.

Thanks.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: @Ingo: I think you're wasting bandwidth my friend :)  Herman's profile says. "Last seen Oct 14 '16 at 4:37" Presumably, he's still making antenna measurements?